# How to reset warnings in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4

Is there a way to reset all warnings/errors in a Xcode 4 project? Xcode 4 shows me errors and warnings e.g. `Unused variable 'pageType'` which is has been removed weeks ago or `'XXXXViewController' undeclared (first use in this function)` which was only for testing purposes and has also gone.

I can't find any options how to get rid of these messages!
Andy tips? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the clean menu option, and then built?

Comment: Latest Xcode? I had some of these type of problems in 4.0 that are largely gone in 4.0.2

Comment: Yes, tried several times to clean, no change. Also upgraded a few weeks ago from 4.0 to 4.0.2 also no change.

Comment: I get this problem in Xcode 7.1 now, I tried clean, then manually deleting the DerivedData folder contents, this didn't work. Luckily restarting Xcode cleared the errors!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably time to remove the project's derived data. Open the organizer, then the Projects tab. Select your project then hit the delete button next to the derived data path (to the right). Confirm and let it re-index your project.